# How to attach a new BrowserWindowOpener to a button, without destroying the button first?

Tags: vaadin

on Vaadin 7 I have the working code :

```
private void gridAttachmentsClickItemEventAction(ItemClickEvent event) {

// blablabla  some code to get the data from the repository

   byte[] data = bibocoAttachmentResponseEntity.getBody().getContent();
    StreamResource.StreamSource source = convertByteArrayToStreamResource(data);
    String filename = "c:\\droppdf\\" 
      +"temp"+bibocoAttachmentResponseEntity.getBody().getFileName()+LocalDate.now().toString();
    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, filename);
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
    resource.getStream().setParameter("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(resource);
    opener.extend(btnAttachmentPreview);
}
```

When I click on a grid row, the data is collected from that grid
and code following on it gets the data byte[] from a repository by calling a service.

Afterwards, when the user clicks on btnAttachmentPreview a new browser tab opens
and shows the pdf (that's what's in the data byte[])

This works fine the first time, but when I select a new row in the grid,
the problem is that the second call does not set the listener to the button right.
It show the first data byte[] again in a new tab, not the current data ...
The method is accessed, the correct data[] has been loaded in the array the second time, I checked.

I believe the listener on the btnAttachmentPreview attached due the code

```
opener.extend(btnAttachmentPreview);
```

should be binned (empty'ed or nulled)  first. But I have no reference to it as for as I can tell.
Problem is that I don't want to destroy the btnAttachmentPreview object.
(The btnAttachmentPreview is a global variable and is set to a layout that I may not change. I know, not nice, but it's a ancient product)

When I close the browser and restart and clicking another row, the right data byte[] is showed.

Anyone a clue ?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove an extension using its `remove()` method, i.e. `opener.remove();`.

If you cannot easily structure your code to store a reference to the old opener so that you have it available when you want to add a new one, then you can use `btnAttachmentPreview.getExtensions()` to get a collection of all current extensions and then from that you can find the appropriate extension (if any) and call `remove()` on it.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I now remove all the extensions before I add a new one and it does the job.